# java - spring - xsl transformation dtd not found error

Tags: java, spring, xslt, transformation, dtd

I have a code which transform xml file using xsl, my peace of code as following. My problem is when i run the execution point it gives me following error.

```
StackTrace: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: /home/app/myapp/bin/xhtml11-flat.dtd (No such file or directory)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:720)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
    at com.core.util.XmlUtils.transform(XmlUtils.java:151)
    at com.core.util.XmlUtils.transform(XmlUtils.java:147)
```

Long story short it is trying to find dtd file inside the bin directory from where i executed the application.

**/home/app/myapp/bin/xhtml11-flat.dtd**

I have the xhtml11-flat.dtd file if i copy this file in bin directory it works fine, instead of the bin directory i want to load it from classpath any idea how can i achieve this with minimum changes ?
I don't know from where it is laoding .dtd code so that i can set my path in it.

```
//Execution Point
function transform(){
    Templates templates = getTemplates();
    StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
    XmlUtils.transform(templates.newTransformer(), input, new StreamResult(result));

    ...
}

private Templates getTemplates() throws Exception {
    if (templates == null) {
        templates = XmlUtils.createTemplates(XslRdcSourceDocTransformer.class.getResourceAsStream("/xsl/" + getXslFileName()));
    }
    return templates;
}


public static Templates createTemplates(InputStream stream) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    return tfactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(stream));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your xml files are probably containing a doctype declaration containing a relative path to the dtd:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "xhtml11-flat.dtd">
```

The transformer api tries to resolve this path to the current working directory of the java program. To customize how the path is resolved you need to implement a [`EntityResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html). This `EntityResolver` can return an [`InputSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) referring to a copy of the dtd loaded from the classpath.

```
public InputSource resolveEntity(final String publicId, final String systemId) throws SAXException {
    if ("xhtml11-flat.dtd".equals(systemId)) {
        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setSystemId(systemId);
        is.setByteStream(cl.getResourceAsStream("/com/example/dtd/xhtml11-flat.dtd"));
        return is;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How you use this class depends on the type of source for your transformation. For a `DOMSource` you have to configure the `DocumentBuilder`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
DocumentBuilder builder = ...
builder.setEntityResolver(entityResolver);

Source source = new DOMSource(builder.parse(inputStream));
```

For a `SAXSource` the setting is on the `XMLReader` instance:

```
SAXParserFactory factory1 = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory1.setValidating(false);
factory1.setNamespaceAware(true);

SAXParser parser = factory1.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
xmlreader.setEntityResolver(entityResolver);

Source source = new SAXSource(xmlreader, new InputSource(stream));
```

The code for the transformation is the same regardless of the source type and should look similar to the code you currently have in your `XmlUtils` class:

```
Templates templates = ...
Result result = new StreamResult(...);
Transformer transformer = templates.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: I appriciate your answer, can you please tell me how can fit DomSource with transform method.

Comment: @Faisalkhan: I added examples for SAXSource and the transformation itself, the code should be similar to that in your XmlUtils class.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me to fixed critical issue

Comment: i am getting 
StackTrace: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:239)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)

Comment: i am getting 
StackTrace: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:239)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)

Comment: Are you reading from the inputstream before or after creation of the source object? If not, that sounds like a problem with the input file. Can you post the file or a sample reproducing the problem as a new question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995731/java-xsl-transformation-dtd-as-entity-resolver-premature-end-of-file